# The usage of " do " and " does " :

Tags: word-usage

Regarding the usage of " do  " and " does " :

"I" is a first person
"you" and "we" are second person.
"they" is third person.

Then why following "they" we have to use the form "does"?

Eg.
instead of "They do not come." 
rather than we say " They does not come"

why?

Comment: You *don't* say "they does not come".

Answer (score 2):

You are only half-right as far as third person is concerned:

The "special" verb form is used for *third person **singular*** only.

Hence:

> - "He **does** not come." but
> - "They **do** not come."

Answer (score 1):

Let me correct the OP as follows:

- the pronoun "we" isn't second person. It's the first person plural form. "I" is the first person singular form.
- you is the second person singular as well as plural form.
- He, she, it are the third person singular forms, whereas "they" is the third person plural form.

You use the auxiliary "do" for I, we, you, and they.

You use the auxiliary "does" for he, she, it.

So it's incorrect that we say They does not come. Instead, we say They do not come.